# Free skills/qualifications database

Tags: database, human-resources

I'm not sure if this is the correct place to ask this kind of question but I'm looking for a freely available, free of charge (or at least not expensive) database with list of skills/qualifications a person can have. I've tried itsyourskills.com but I find it quite expensive.

Does any one of you know any resource out there I could try?